# Create a new column by concating two string columns together

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Looking to combine two string columns into a new column in a dataframe.

For instance -

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Primary Type':['a','b','c'],'Description':['1','2','3']})
>>> df

  Primary Type Description
0            a           1
1            b           2
2            c           3
```

I'd like the output to be

```
  Primary Type Description combined
0            a           1     a ,1
1            b           2     b ,2
2            c           3     c ,3
```

Here's what's been tried -

```
df['combined'] = df['Primary Type'] + ', ' + df['Description']
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Other ideas?

Comment: I just tried your code and what you "tried" actually works for me.  Why does it not "seem to work" for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
df['combined'] = df['Primary Type'].map(str) + ' ,' +
df['Description'].map(str)

df 
Primary Type Description combined            
a            1           a ,1 
b            2           b ,2          
c            3           c ,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter your code by using `join` after convert to `str`

```
df['New']=df.astype(str).apply(','.join,1)
df
  Primary Type Description  New
0            a           1  a,1
1            b           2  b,2
2            c           3  c,3
```